Images are not loading in ejs file
When the request is made on /blog images are loaded in EJS file rendering to blog.ejs,
but when the request is made on /blog/comment/add/:blogId the viewComment.ejs file loads but images don't.
I have use blogRoute.use(express.static(path.resolve("public"))).
I don't understand why one EJS file is loading the images and other don't when the same route is use for rendering to pages
BLOG.EJS(images loading here)
<% if (locals.allBlogs) { %>
            <% allBlogs.reverse().forEach((blog) => { %>
                <div class="card blogCard" >
                    <% if (blog.thumbnail != '') { %>
                        <img src="<%= blog.thumbnail %>" class="thumbnail" >
                    <% } %> 
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="/blog/comment/<%= blog._id %>"><h5 class="card-title"><%= blog.title %></h5></a>
                        <p class="card-text"><%= blog.message %></p>
                    </div>
                    <img src=<%= locals.blogCreater.profilePicture%> class="card-img-top" style="height:30px; width: 30px;margin-bottom:0px">
                    <div class="card-body" style="height: 20px;padding: 0px;margin-left: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                        <span class="card-title" style="font-size: 15px;"><%=locals.blogCreater.userName %></span>
                    </div>

                </div>    
                  
            <% }) %>
        
    <% } %>



viewCOmment.ejs (images not loading)
     <% if (blog.thumbnail != '') { %>
                    <img src=<%= blog.thumbnail %> class="thumbnail" >
                <% } %> 
                <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title"><%= blog.title %></h5>
                    <p class="card-text"><%= blog.message %></p>
                </div>
                <% if (locals.creator) { %>
                    <img src=<%=creator.profilePicture%> class="card-img-top" style="height:30px; width: 30px;margin-bottom:0px">
                    <div class="card-body" style="height: 20px;padding: 0px;margin-left: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;">
                        <span class="card-title" style="font-size: 15px;"><%=creator.userName %></span>
                    </div>
                <% } %>


Could you share the rendered html and the ejs template used?

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network

on trying on the same issue i found that when i changed the /blog/comment/add/:blogId  to /blog/comment/:blogId  it worked images are now loading in ejs file.
i dont know why the previous address was not working.
Can anyone tell why that was happening.

Could you share the routing of the paths? Also, I doubt this is the case, but if the two templates are in different folders you need to adjust the relative path. And are there any error messages in the console?

well both blog.ejs and viewComment.ejs are in same folder i.e is views

Try adding base tag to root EJS template so that the images use consistent path:
  <base href="/" target="_blank">


The <base> HTML element specifies the base URL to
use for all relative URLs in a document. There can be only
one <base> element in a document.

